# Use partial on my web to show main slide on C# MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use partial on my web to show main slide but when i use partial i keep getting error. Help me please. 
Here my some code:
On Controller

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    public ActionResult TestSnew()
    {
        var snew = db.Snews;
        return PartialView(snew);
    }
```

On View

```
@model Jiremsenmn.Models.Snew
Some Html code to shown
```

On Layout

```
@Html.Partial("TestSnew")
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? What solutions have you tried?

Comment: “Hello guys I need some help” — Yeah, who doesn’t on this site? Please edit and come up with a title that describes the problem.

Comment: at @Html.Partial("TestSnew"). It said "InvaledOperationException was unhandled by user code"

Comment: @Timwi thank you for advice. But i said "on C# MVC" :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a Model of Snews (plural) , when your view is expecting just one Snew.

Try this:

```
var snew = db.Snews.FirstOrDefault();
```

When you are in the context of a View, you are expected to have your information ready to be displayed.

You did that in your fist example PartialView(snew) when retrieving from your DB and sending it to the View.

But in your second example you are already on the view, so here you have to create your Snew object, so let's suppose that Snew Class is simple and it has two properties, something like:

```
public class Snew {
  public String Title { get; set;}
  public String Description { get; set;}
}
```

So within the context of your View, you have to populate the object yourself to send it to HtmlPartial, something like this:

```
 @{
   var mySnew = new Snew { Title="Title created dynamically", Description="something else"};

  //now that you have the model (the Snew), you can use Partial

  Html.Partial("SnewTest",mySnew);
 }
```

***NOTE*** make sure you reference the Snew class correctly with the using statement in your view

hope it helps,

Comment: tried this one but still getting error at @Html.Partial("TestSnew"). It says InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code.

Comment: that's because you are not sending the model on that one:

Comment: you need to create a model first, try this: @Html.Partial("TestSnew",SnewObjectCreatedByYou)

Comment: But what model and what will it do? i mean that partial should display picture from database on my website. i am new on C# .